# How to communicate with fragment from my adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created a custom adapter class. In that class, I have a code that will have to send a message to my fragment, when I clicked on my listview layout.
After googling, the best approach to do it may be using interface. Most of them are the example of communicating between activity with the fragment. But in my case, I don't have any ideas about how to communicate between my adapter class with my fragment class. 
let says I create an interface in my adapter class like:

```
public interface SuccessResponse{
    void onSuccess();
}
```

and on the LinearLayout inside my adapter class I want it to be something like:

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        SuccessResponse.onSuccess();
    }
})
```

Then I want to make sure my fragment page get the onSuccess() method and do something like :

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment implements Adapter.SuccessResponse{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(){
        //do Something
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like above?

Comment: Pass the instance to fragment to your custom adapter through constructor.

Comment: the way you are calling `onSuccess()` inside `onClick()` method is wrong... It should be called on fragment as it is Fragment's method.

Comment: so, how to do it if I want it to call onSuccess() when the item is clicked?

Comment: Can you show me how to do the constructor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**
If you are looking for a solution in Kotlin

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = MyAdapter(){
            Log.d("zzzz", "$it ")
        }
    }
}


class MyAdapter (val onClick : (value: String) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClick("something")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

**JAVA**
The following code may help you.

```
    public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.SuccessResponse{
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View contentView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), 0);
            myAdapter.successResponse = this;
            return contentView;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
    
        }
    }

    
    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
        SuccessResponse successResponse;
    
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }
    
        public interface SuccessResponse{
            void onSuccess();
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //ur views
            linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view){
                    if(successResponse!=null)
                        successResponse.onSuccess();
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: on the onSuccess() method in my fragment, I put a Log.d to print something, and it shows me that the program never reach it. Maybe because of my successResponse==null?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to initialize it inside my fragment, it's working now, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your CustomAdapter

1) Import Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

2) Declare frag object in your adapter

```
     Fragment frag

        public YourAdapter(Fragment frag) {
            this.frag = frag;
        }
```

3) Now call your fragment method

```
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                ((HomeFragment) frag).onSuccess();// here your fragment name HomeFragment
            }
        })
```

4) In HomeFragment

```
    public void onSuccess(){
         // do your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Why not just pass the `Adapter.SuccessResponse`. The whole Fragment is useless within the Adapter.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, he can do by this way also.

Comment: Right here you are coupling the Adapter to the Fragment. The Adapter should only care about a `Adapter.SuccessResponse`, not depend on a Fragment to exist.

Comment: So when I initialize my adapter, it will be something like this : CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter (FragmentClass.class)?

Comment: No, Pass your Fragment's object instead of FragmentClass.class.