# Calling an adapter method in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, searchview

Friends , I have a fragment with a search-view and recyclerview in it. I want to implement that search-view on the recyclerview data.I am facing problem when i try to call a method from my adapter class in my fragment it does not allow it and asks me to make the method in adapter class as static which is not fine.Here's the required fragment code -

```
 private void processQuery(String query) {
        // in real app you'd have it instantiated just once
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // case insensitive search
        for (String category : category_name) {
            if (category.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                result.add(category);
            }
        }

        (MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter.setCategorynames(result);
    }
```

I am getting error on this line-

```
(MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter.setCategorynames(result);
```

Here's my MyAdaper declaration and initialization -

```
RecyclerView.Adapter MyAdapter;
 MyAdapter = new MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox(getMyCategoryAdapter1, getActivity().getApplicationContext(),category_name);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
```

And here's my adapter class (setCategorynames) method.It is asking me to make this method as static -

```
public  void setCategorynames(List<String> category_name) {
        this.category_name = category_name;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

So i want to know how can i call a method of adapter class in a fragment?
My adapter class code-

```
public class MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox.ViewHolder> {
    List<GetMyCategoryAdapter> getMyCategoryAdapter;
    Context context;
    List<String> category_name;
   GetMyCategoryAdapter getMyCategoryAdapter1;

    public MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox(List<GetMyCategoryAdapter> getMyCategoryAdapter, Context context, List<String> category_name) {
    this.getMyCategoryAdapter = getMyCategoryAdapter;
    this.context = context;
    this.category_name = category_name;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof ViewHolder){
        }
        getMyCategoryAdapter1 =  getMyCategoryAdapter.get(i);
      ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_categorytitle.setText(getMyCategoryAdapter1.getC_name());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_categoryid.setText(getMyCategoryAdapter1.getC_id());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).gt= getMyCategoryAdapter1;
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filterdNames) {
        this.category_name = filterdNames;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use interface instead of this.

Comment: @HemantParmar how??  please elaborate..Actually i am new to android

Comment: Can you show your Fragment code?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444411/5110595) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546822/5110595)

Comment: @payal_suthar is `category_name` somewhere declared as static?

Comment: MyAdapter .update() simply create a method and call it using adapter object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one issue i see in your code, that `setCategorynames(List<String> category_name) method is not resolved` because `MyAdapter` is not casted to `(MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox)`

You need to replace

`(MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter.setCategorynames(result);`

by this

`((MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter).setCategorynames(result);`

Comment: thanks it worked but can u let me know why is my notifydatachanged() method not working ? i am using an edittext for search feature but on text changed it is fetching the data but not updating the recycler view data

Comment: @payal_suthar not in comments please

Comment: then how?you want me to update the question? but the question is not relevant to what i asked before

Comment: updated the question and added the code.Have a look

Comment: maybe let's create chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191227/discussion-between-payal-suthar-and-yuri-popiv).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an interface like that;

```
public interface ProcessQueryListener{
     void onSuccess(List<String> result);
}
```

In your adapter, you should implements this listener as you wish. Basically like that :

```
public MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements ProcessQueryListener {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<String> result){
         this.setCategorynames(result);
    }
}
.
.
```

In your fragment's processQuery  function you should invoke this ProcessQueryListener. Such as;

```
ProcessQueryListener queryListener = (MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter;

private void processQuery(String query) {
        // in real app you'd have it instantiated just once
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // case insensitive search
        for (String category : category_name) {
            if (category.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                result.add(category);
            }
        }

        if (queryListener != null) {
           queryListener.onSuccess(result);
        }
}
```